# Get a "Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)" in Excel 2016 but not in Excel 2011

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

Here's the relevant code in the BurnUpApplication Module:

```
For Each slice In slices
    graph.drawSlice slice
Next
```

Which calls the following code in a CBurnUp class:

```
Public Sub drawSlice(slice As CSlice)
    With self.SeriesCollection.Add(slice.CumulativeSizeRange())
            .xValues = mXAxis
            .name = slice.name
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(slice.Color_Red, slice.Color_Green, slice.Color_Blue)
    End With
    sliceCounter = sliceCounter + 1
End Sub
```

Which calls the following code in CSlice class:

```
Public Property Get CumulativeSizeRange() As Range
    Set CumulativeSizeRange = mSizeCumulative
End Property
```

This works fine in Excel 2011!!

---

Here's the full project code:

### BurnUpApplication Module

```
Option Explicit
Dim graph As CBurnUp
Const PROJECT_WS_NAME = "Project"
Const TEMPLATE_WS_NAME = "Template"
Const DATA_TABLE_WS_NAME = "DataTable"
Const BURNUP_WS_NAME = "BurnUp"

Sub onClick_UpdateBurnUp()
    WaitDialog.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Sub UpdateBurnup()
    Dim projectWs As Worksheet
    Set projectWs = Worksheets(PROJECT_WS_NAME)
    UpdateDataTableSlices projectWs, Worksheets(DATA_TABLE_WS_NAME)

    Set graph = New CBurnUp
    graph.init Worksheets(BURNUP_WS_NAME).ChartObjects(1).Chart

    Dim slice As CSlice
    Dim slices As Collection
    Dim dateRange As Range

    graph.clean

    With projectWs
        graph.XAxis = Union(getVisibleDataFrom(.Columns(1)), _
                                getVisibleDataFrom(.Columns(2)), _
                                getVisibleDataFrom(.Columns(3)))
        Set dateRange = getVisibleDataFrom(.Columns(3))
    End With

    Set slices = getSliceList

    For Each slice In slices
        graph.drawSlice slice
    Next

    graph.drawForecast getVisibleDataFrom(Worksheets(DATA_TABLE_WS_NAME).Columns(getProperty("CURRENT_FORECAST_COLUMN")))
    graph.drawBurnedPoints getVisibleDataFrom(Worksheets(DATA_TABLE_WS_NAME).Columns(getProperty("BURNED_POINTS_COLUMN")))

    drawPlannedDatesAndContingency graph, slices, getPlannedBurnUp

    For Each slice In slices
        graph.drawSliceName slice
        graph.drawReleaseDate slice, dateRange
        graph.drawMilestoneDate slice, dateRange

    Next

    Unload WaitDialog
    Worksheets("BurnUp").Activate
End Sub

Sub onClick_SetPlan()
    Dim currentForecast As Range
    Dim plannedBurnup As Range

    If getProperty("IS_PROJECT_STARTED") = True Then
        Dim dialogResult As VbMsgBoxResult
        dialogResult = MsgBox("You have choosen to Set a new Baseline. Contingency and expectations will be changed accoring to the current velocity. Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "Burnup - Rebase")
        If dialogResult = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    'take forecasted burnup
    Set currentForecast = getDataFrom(Worksheets(DATA_TABLE_WS_NAME).Columns(getProperty("CURRENT_FORECAST_COLUMN")))
    'copy to Planned BurnUp
    Set plannedBurnup = getDataFrom(Worksheets(PROJECT_WS_NAME).Columns(getProperty("PLANNED_FORECAST_COLUMN")))
    currentForecast.Copy
    plannedBurnup.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ' if there is a sampled average velocity change the avg
    updatePlannedVelocityWithSampledOne
    updateSliceSize Worksheets(PROJECT_WS_NAME)
    'the planned velocity
End Sub

Sub updatePlannedVelocityWithSampledOne()
    Dim plannedVelPerEng As Range
    Dim sampledVelPerEng As Range

    Set plannedVelPerEng = Worksheets(PROJECT_WS_NAME).Cells(getProperty("PLANNED_VEL_ROW"), getProperty("PLANNED_VEL_COL"))
    Set sampledVelPerEng = Worksheets(PROJECT_WS_NAME).Cells(getProperty("SAMPLED_VEL_ROW"), getProperty("SAMPLED_VEL_COL")) ''

    If Not WorksheetFunction.IsNA(sampledVelPerEng) Then
            plannedVelPerEng.Value = sampledVelPerEng.Value
    End If
End Sub

Sub updateSliceSize(inWs As Worksheet)
    Dim isStart, isEnd As Byte
    Dim iCursor As Byte
    Dim currentIteration As Byte
    Dim firstDataRow As Byte

    firstDataRow = getProperty("FIRST_DATA_ROW")
    isStart = getProperty("PROJECT_SLICES_START_COLUMN") + 1
    isEnd = getProperty("PROJECT_SLICES_END_COLUMN")
    currentIteration = getProperty("CURRENT_ITERATION_INDEX") + firstDataRow

    iCursor = isStart

        Do While iCursor < isEnd
            inWs.Cells(2, iCursor).Formula = "=" & inWs.Cells(currentIteration, iCursor).Address(False, False)
            inWs.Cells(currentIteration, iCursor).Interior.Color = inWs.Cells(firstDataRow, iCursor).Interior.Color
            iCursor = iCursor + 1
       Loop
End Sub


Sub drawPlannedDatesAndContingency(burnUp As CBurnUp, slices As Collection, plannedBurnup As Range)
    Dim s As CSlice
    Dim i As Byte
    Dim contingencySize As Double
    Dim currentIteration As Byte
    currentIteration = 0

    For Each s In slices
        s.StartingIteration = currentIteration
        For i = 1 To plannedBurnup.Count
            If (plannedBurnup.Cells(i).Value >= s.CumulativeWithContingency) Then
                currentIteration = i
                If s.contingency > 0 Then
                    contingencySize = getContingencySize(s, plannedBurnup, s.StartingIteration, currentIteration)
                    burnUp.drawContingency i, s.Cumulative(i), contingencySize
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Function getContingencySize(slice As CSlice, plannedBurnup As Range, startIt As Byte, endIt As Byte) As Double

Dim contingencySize As Double
' previous version with linear velocity
        'contingencySize = contingency / averageSliceVelocity(plannedBurnup, startIt, endIt)
        'contingencySize = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(contingencySize, 2)


Dim i As Byte
Dim burnedPoints As Double
Dim remainingContingency As Double

i = endIt
remainingContingency = slice.contingency
' new version based on burned points

Do While remainingContingency > 0
    burnedPoints = plannedBurnup.Cells(i) - plannedBurnup.Cells(i - 1)
    If remainingContingency > burnedPoints Then
        remainingContingency = remainingContingency - burnedPoints
        contingencySize = contingencySize + 1
    Else
        contingencySize = contingencySize + remainingContingency / burnedPoints
        remainingContingency = 0
    End If
    i = i - 1
Loop
    getContingencySize = contingencySize

End Function

Function averageSliceVelocity(plannedBurnup As Range, startIt As Byte, endIt As Byte) As Double

    If (endIt - startIt) = 0 Then
     'if the slice is completed in one iteration the avg velovity is the velocity of that iteration
        averageSliceVelocity = (plannedBurnup.Cells(endIt).Value - plannedBurnup.Cells(endIt - 1).Value)
    Else
        averageSliceVelocity = (plannedBurnup.Cells(endIt).Value - plannedBurnup.Cells(startIt).Value) / (endIt - startIt)
    End If

End Function


Function createSlice(sliceRange As Range) As CSlice
    Dim slice As CSlice
    Set slice = New CSlice
    slice.init sliceRange
    Set createSlice = slice
End Function

Function getSliceList() As Collection
    Dim slices As Collection
    Dim sStart, sEnd As Byte
    Set slices = New Collection
    sStart = getProperty("SLICES_START_COLUMN") + 1
    sEnd = getProperty("SLICES_END_COLUMN")

    Do While sStart < sEnd
        With Worksheets(DATA_TABLE_WS_NAME)
            slices.Add createSlice(Union(.Columns(sStart), .Columns(sStart + 1), .Columns(sStart + 2)))
        End With
        sStart = sStart + 3
    Loop
    Set getSliceList = slices

End Function

Function getPlannedBurnUp() As Range
    Set getPlannedBurnUp = getVisibleDataFrom(Worksheets(PROJECT_WS_NAME).Columns(getProperty("PLANNED_FORECAST_COLUMN")))
End Function

Function getVisibleDataFrom(Column As Range) As Range
    Set getVisibleDataFrom = Column.Worksheet.Range(Column.Cells(getProperty("FIRST_DATA_ROW"), 1), _
            Column.Cells(getProperty("LAST_DATA_ROW"), 1))
End Function

Function getDataFrom(Column As Range) As Range
    Set getDataFrom = Column.Worksheet.Range(Column.Cells(getProperty("FIRST_DATA_ROW"), 1), _
            Column.Cells(getProperty("MAX_NUMBER_OF_IT"), 1))
End Function

Sub UpdateDataTableSlices(inWs As Worksheet, outWs As Worksheet)
    Dim osStart, osEnd, isStart, isEnd As Byte
    Dim iCursor, oCursor As Byte

    osStart = getProperty("SLICES_START_COLUMN") + 1
    osEnd = getProperty("SLICES_END_COLUMN")

    isStart = getProperty("PROJECT_SLICES_START_COLUMN") + 1
    isEnd = getProperty("PROJECT_SLICES_END_COLUMN")

    If Not (osStart = osEnd) Then
        outWs.Columns(osStart).Resize(, osEnd - osStart).Delete
    End If

    If Not (isStart = isEnd) Then
        outWs.Columns(osStart).Resize(, (isEnd - isStart) * 3).Insert
    End If

        iCursor = isStart
        oCursor = osStart

        Do While iCursor < isEnd
            inWs.Columns(iCursor).Copy
            outWs.Columns(oCursor).PasteSpecial
            ' copy cumulative column from template
            Worksheets(TEMPLATE_WS_NAME).Columns(5).Copy
            outWs.Columns(oCursor + 1).PasteSpecial
            ' copy contingency column from template
            Worksheets(TEMPLATE_WS_NAME).Columns(6).Copy
            outWs.Columns(oCursor + 2).PasteSpecial

            oCursor = oCursor + 3
            iCursor = iCursor + 1
       Loop

       'This line is added because when exit from Excel the application ask if you want to save the data in clipboard
        Worksheets(TEMPLATE_WS_NAME).Cells(1, 1).Copy
End Sub
```

---

### CBurnUp Class

```
Option Explicit
Const CONTINGENCY_RECT_HEIGHT = 6
Const CONTINGENCY_SCALE = 6
Private unitPerIteration As Double
Private unitPerValueY As Double
Private self As Chart

Private originX, originY As Double
Private sliceCounter As Byte
Private mXAxis As Range
Private NUMBER_OF_IT_TO_DISPLAY As Byte

Public Sub init(chartInstance As Chart)
    Set self = chartInstance
    NUMBER_OF_IT_TO_DISPLAY = getProperty("NUMBER_OF_IT_TO_DISPLAY")
End Sub

Property Let XAxis(xValues As Range)
    Set mXAxis = xValues
End Property


Public Sub drawSlice(slice As CSlice)
    With self.SeriesCollection.Add(slice.CumulativeSizeRange())
            .xValues = mXAxis
            .name = slice.name
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(slice.Color_Red, slice.Color_Green, slice.Color_Blue)
    End With
    sliceCounter = sliceCounter + 1
End Sub

Public Sub drawForecast(forecastRange As Range)
    Dim newRange As Range
    Set newRange = forecastRange

        With self.SeriesCollection.Add(forecastRange)
            .xValues = mXAxis
            .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash
            .name = "Forecast"
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(105, 140, 140)
        End With
End Sub
Public Sub drawBurnedPoints(burnedPoints As Range)
    With self.SeriesCollection.Add(burnedPoints)
            .xValues = mXAxis
            .name = "BurnedPoints"
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(233, 91, 80)
            End With
End Sub

Public Sub clean()
        Dim s As Series
        Dim sh As Shape

        For Each s In self.SeriesCollection
              s.Delete
        Next s
        For Each sh In self.Shapes
              sh.Delete
        Next sh

        sliceCounter = 0
End Sub

Public Sub drawContingency(forecastedIteration As Byte, scope As Double, contingSize As Double)

If scope = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

        Dim rectPosX, rectPosY As Double
        Dim rectW, rectH As Double
    If (contingSize > 0) Then
        With self.PlotArea
            originY = .InsideTop
            originX = .InsideLeft

            unitPerIteration = .InsideWidth / NUMBER_OF_IT_TO_DISPLAY
            unitPerValueY = .InsideHeight / self.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale

                rectW = getUnitsForItPerc(contingSize)
                rectH = CONTINGENCY_RECT_HEIGHT
                rectPosX = .InsideLeft + (forecastedIteration * unitPerIteration) - rectW - (unitPerIteration / 2)
                rectPosY = .InsideTop + .InsideHeight - (scope * unitPerValueY) - (rectH / 2)
                ' Create Rect
                    With self.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, rectPosX, rectPosY, rectW, rectH)
                        With .Fill
                            .Visible = True
                            .ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
                            .BackColor.RGB = vbYellow
                        End With
                        With .Line
                            .Visible = True
                            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                            .BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                        End With
                    End With
        End With
        End If
        drawLine forecastedIteration
End Sub

Public Sub drawSliceName(slice As CSlice)
        Dim txtPosX, txtPosY As Double
        Dim rectW, rectH As Double

        With self.PlotArea
            originY = .InsideTop
            originX = .InsideLeft

            unitPerIteration = .InsideWidth / NUMBER_OF_IT_TO_DISPLAY
            unitPerValueY = .InsideHeight / self.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale

                txtPosX = .width + .InsideLeft
                txtPosY = .InsideTop + .InsideHeight - (slice.Cumulative(NUMBER_OF_IT_TO_DISPLAY) * unitPerValueY)
                ' Create Rect
                With self.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, txtPosX, txtPosY, self.ChartArea.width - .width - .Left, 60)
                    .TextFrame.AutoSize = False
                    .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 14
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = slice.name
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = RGB(slice.Color_Red, slice.Color_Green, slice.Color_Blue)
                    .Left = .Left + .width
                    .Top = .Top - (.height / 2)
                End With
          End With
End Sub


Private Sub drawLine(forecastedIteration As Byte)
    Dim linePosX, linePosY As Double
    With self.PlotArea
            unitPerIteration = .InsideWidth / NUMBER_OF_IT_TO_DISPLAY
            unitPerValueY = .InsideHeight / self.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale

            linePosX = .InsideLeft + (forecastedIteration * unitPerIteration) - (unitPerIteration / 2)
            linePosY = .InsideTop

            ' Create line
            With self.Shapes.AddLine(linePosX, linePosY, linePosX, .InsideHeight + .InsideTop)
                 .Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash
                 .Line.Weight = xlThin
                 .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(150, 150, 150)
            End With
    End With
End Sub
Private Function getUnitsForItPerc(iterationPercentage As Double)
    getUnitsForItPerc = unitPerIteration * iterationPercentage
End Function

Public Sub drawReleaseDate(slice As CSlice, dateRange As Range)
    Dim chart_x, chart_y As Double
    Dim release_date As Date
    Dim width, height As Double
    Dim forecasted_iteration As Double
    Dim previous_iteration_end_date, next_iteration_end_date As Date

    If slice.HasAReleseDate = True Then
        release_date = slice.ReleaseDate
        If dateRange(1, 1) > release_date Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If dateRange(NUMBER_OF_IT_TO_DISPLAY, 1) < release_date Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

        With self.PlotArea
            originY = .InsideTop
            originX = .InsideLeft

            unitPerIteration = .InsideWidth / NUMBER_OF_IT_TO_DISPLAY
            unitPerValueY = .InsideHeight / self.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale
            forecasted_iteration = WorksheetFunction.Match(Int(CDbl(release_date)), dateRange, 1)
            previous_iteration_end_date = dateRange(forecasted_iteration, 1).Value
            next_iteration_end_date = dateRange(forecasted_iteration + 1, 1).Value
            forecasted_iteration = forecasted_iteration + (release_date - previous_iteration_end_date) _
                                                / (next_iteration_end_date - previous_iteration_end_date)
                width = 16
                height = 16
                chart_x = .InsideLeft + (forecasted_iteration * unitPerIteration) - (unitPerIteration / 2) - (width / 2)
                chart_y = .InsideTop + .InsideHeight - ((slice.Cumulative(forecasted_iteration)) * unitPerValueY)
                ' Create Rect
                    With self.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, chart_x, chart_y, width, height)
                        With .Fill
                            .Visible = True
                            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(slice.Color_Red, slice.Color_Green, slice.Color_Blue)
                            .BackColor.RGB = RGB(slice.Color_Red, slice.Color_Green, slice.Color_Blue)
                        End With
                        With .Line
                            .Visible = True
                            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(slice.Color_Red, slice.Color_Green, slice.Color_Blue)
                            .BackColor.RGB = RGB(slice.Color_Red, slice.Color_Green, slice.Color_Blue)
                        End With
                    End With
        End With
End Sub

Public Sub drawMilestoneDate(slice As CSlice, dateRange As Range)
    Dim chart_x, chart_y As Double
    Dim release_date As Date
    Dim width, height As Double
    Dim forecasted_iteration As Double
    Dim previous_iteration_end_date, next_iteration_end_date As Date

    If slice.HasAMilestoneDate = True Then
        release_date = slice.MilestoneDate
        If dateRange(1, 1) > release_date Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If dateRange(NUMBER_OF_IT_TO_DISPLAY, 1) < release_date Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

        With self.PlotArea
            originY = .InsideTop
            originX = .InsideLeft

            unitPerIteration = .InsideWidth / NUMBER_OF_IT_TO_DISPLAY
            unitPerValueY = .InsideHeight / self.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale
            forecasted_iteration = WorksheetFunction.Match(Int(CDbl(release_date)), dateRange, 1)
            previous_iteration_end_date = dateRange(forecasted_iteration, 1).Value
            next_iteration_end_date = dateRange(forecasted_iteration + 1, 1).Value
            forecasted_iteration = forecasted_iteration + (release_date - previous_iteration_end_date) _
                                                / (next_iteration_end_date - previous_iteration_end_date)
                width = 16
                height = 16
                chart_x = .InsideLeft + (forecasted_iteration * unitPerIteration) - (unitPerIteration / 2) - (width / 2)
                chart_y = .InsideTop + .InsideHeight - ((slice.Cumulative(forecasted_iteration)) * unitPerValueY) - (height / 2)
                ' Create Rect
                    With self.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeDiamond, chart_x, chart_y, width, height)
                        With .Fill
                            .Visible = True
                            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                            .BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                        End With
                        With .Line
                            .Visible = True
                            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                            .BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                        End With
                    End With
        End With
End Sub
```

---

### CSlice Class

```
Option Explicit

Const TPL_THIRD_COLUMN = 3
Const TPL_SECOND_COLUMN = 2
Const TPL_FIRST_COLUMN = 1

Private mSizeCumulative As Range
Private mCumulativeSizeWithContingency As Double
Private mSizeWithPreviousContingency As Double

Private mSize As Range
Private mPlannedSize As Range

Private mName As String
Private mContingency As Double
Private mColor As Range
Private mReleaseDate As Date
Private mMilestoneDate As Date


Private mHasMilestoneDate As Boolean
Private mHasReleaseDate As Boolean
Private mStartingIteration As Byte


Public Sub init(sliceRange As Range)
        'Header
        mName = sliceRange.Cells(getProperty("SLICE_NAME_ROW"), TPL_FIRST_COLUMN)
        mContingency = sliceRange.Cells(getProperty("CONTINGENCY_ROW"), TPL_THIRD_COLUMN)
        mCumulativeSizeWithContingency = sliceRange.Cells(getProperty("SIZE_PLUS_CONT_ROW"), TPL_THIRD_COLUMN)
        mSizeWithPreviousContingency = sliceRange.Cells(getProperty("PLANNED_SIZE_ROW"), TPL_THIRD_COLUMN)
        'Values
        Set mPlannedSize = sliceRange.Cells(getProperty("PLANNED_SIZE_ROW"), TPL_FIRST_COLUMN)
        Set mSize = getVisibleDataFrom(sliceRange.Columns(TPL_FIRST_COLUMN))
        Set mSizeCumulative = getVisibleDataFrom(sliceRange.Columns(TPL_SECOND_COLUMN))


        'Dates
        mHasReleaseDate = Not (sliceRange.Cells(getProperty("RELEASE_DATE_ROW"), TPL_FIRST_COLUMN) = "")
        mReleaseDate = sliceRange.Cells(getProperty("RELEASE_DATE_ROW"), TPL_FIRST_COLUMN)
        mHasMilestoneDate = Not (sliceRange.Cells(getProperty("MILESTONE_DATE_ROW"), TPL_FIRST_COLUMN) = "")
        mMilestoneDate = sliceRange.Cells(getProperty("MILESTONE_DATE_ROW"), TPL_FIRST_COLUMN)

        'Color
        Set mColor = sliceRange.Cells(getProperty("SLICE_COLOR_ROW"), TPL_FIRST_COLUMN)

End Sub

Property Get CumulativeWithContingency() As Double
    CumulativeWithContingency = mCumulativeSizeWithContingency
End Property
'Current one without contingency plus previous one with cont
Property Get CumulativePreviousContingency() As Double
    CumulativePreviousContingency = mSizeWithPreviousContingency
End Property

Property Get Cumulative(ByVal itIndex As Double) As Double
    Cumulative = mSizeCumulative(itIndex, 1)
End Property

Public Property Get CumulativeSizeRange() As Range
    Set CumulativeSizeRange = mSizeCumulative
End Property
Public Property Get name() As String
    name = mName
End Property

Public Property Let PlannedSize(Size As Double)
    mPlannedSize.Value = Size
End Property

Public Property Get Color_Red() As Integer
    Color_Red = Int(mColor.Interior.Color Mod 256)
End Property
Public Property Get Color_Blue() As Integer
    Color_Blue = Int(mColor.Interior.Color / 256 / 256) Mod 256
End Property
Public Property Get Color_Green() As Integer
    Color_Green = Int(mColor.Interior.Color / 256) Mod 256
End Property
Public Property Get contingency() As Double
    contingency = mContingency
End Property

Public Property Get ReleaseDate() As Date
    ReleaseDate = mReleaseDate
End Property

Public Property Get HasAReleseDate() As Boolean
    HasAReleseDate = mHasReleaseDate
End Property

Public Property Get MilestoneDate() As Date
    MilestoneDate = mMilestoneDate
End Property

Public Property Get HasAMilestoneDate() As Boolean
    HasAMilestoneDate = mMilestoneDate
End Property


Public Property Get StartingIteration() As Byte
    StartingIteration = mStartingIteration
End Property

Public Property Let StartingIteration(it As Byte)
    mStartingIteration = it
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

End Sub
```

---

### Project Class

```
Option Explicit

Private mWS As Worksheet

Public Sub init(projectWs As Worksheet)
    Set mWS = projectWs
End Sub
```

---

### Configuration Module

```
Option Explicit

Const CONF_WORKSHEET_NAME = "Configuration"
Const KEY_COLUMN = 1
Const VAL_COLUMN = 2

Public Function getProperty(name As String)
    Dim confWS As Worksheet
    Set confWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CONF_WORKSHEET_NAME)
    getProperty = WorksheetFunction.Index(confWS.Columns(VAL_COLUMN), WorksheetFunction.Match(name, confWS.Columns(KEY_COLUMN), 0))
End Function
```

Comment: Could you include the code that is getting this property please.

Comment: @Ambie added, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't see where you've called the `init()` routine of class C. Have you definitely defined `mSizeCumulative`?

Comment: @Ambie Alright, the whole enchilada above

Comment: Probably a long shot here, but are both versions of excel 32 bit?

Comment: I can't find the issue, I'm afraid. The only area that might be problematic is that in `getSliceList` you declare (by omission) `sStart` as a Variant. `sStart` calls the property `getProperty` which returns a Variant (again, by omission). It's possible then that `sStart` isn't defining the range you were expecting and this might account for an incorrectly set `mSizeCumulative`. Other than that, I'm out of ideas.